# MySQL Troubles. What should I do?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I make it so that the code

```
$requests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_reqs WHERE user_to={$_SESSION['user']['user_id']}");<br />
$users = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, user_pic FROM users WHERE user_id={?}");

>echo "`<h2>Pending Requests</h2>`";

>echo "`<center><table class='squish'>";
  if(mysql_num_rows($requests) >= 1){
    while($un = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)){
        echo "<tr><form action='' method='post'>";
            echo "<img src='https://www.mastergamersocial.com/user_pics/".$un['user_pic']."' alt='".$un['user_name']."' width='50px' height='50px' />".$un['user_name'];
            echo "<input class='a-button' type='submit' value='Accept' name='yes' />";
            echo "<input class='a-button' type='submit' value='Decline' name='no' />";
        echo "</form><br /></tr>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "<tr><h3>You have no friend requests.</h3></tr>";
  }
echo "</table></center>";
```

Sorry for the sloppy code. I need to get it so that it pulls the user_id and name from the user who sent the request. But I can't figure out how to get it unless i call the query later. But I need the query to be called when it is.

Comment: I really don't understand. What's your trouble?

Comment: I need to find a way to make it so that the user_name and user_pic are coming from user_from. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: So is '**user_from**' the name of the table because I don't see user_from mentioned, anywhere, in your code.

Comment: the $requests is getting user_from and user_to from friend_reqs.

Comment: So `user_from` is a column for the table `friend_reqs`, now what do you need to do with it?

Comment: I need to get user_from to be the ? in $users

Comment: Could you guys up like this so I can post more questions. I got question banned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing from your comments, if you need the first value of `user_from` from `$requests`, you could simply fetch your first record after the query and insert it in the second one like:

```
$requests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_reqs WHERE user_to={$_SESSION['user']['user_id']}");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($requests);
$from_user = $row['user_from'];
$users = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, user_pic FROM users WHERE user_id={$from_user}");
```

Now if your `$requests` is returning multiple records and you want to execute `$users` with each `user_from` value. Then you'll have to run the second query in a loop.

You can have one query being fetched multiple times by different variables, if that's what you were unclear about.

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).